# How to sort out time series data in accordance to x and y address

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series

I am new on stack over flow and I have a time series data having 37 columns (longitude) and 18 rows (latitude) with 9587 observations. The row names are repeating after ever 18 observations.

```
          70.875 71.125 71.375 71.625 71.875 72.125
33.1251      0      0      0      0      0      0
33.3751      0      0      0      0      0      0
33.6251      0      0      0      0      0      0
33.8751      0      0      0      0      0      0
34.1251      0      0      0      0      0      0
34.3751      0      0      0      0      0      0
```

I have to extract each box value separately as like,

```
 latitude1*longitude1 (365 observations)
latitude1*longitude2 (365 observations)
latitude1*longitude3 (365 observations)
In last
latitude18*longitude37 (365 observations)
```

How I can execute this operation in Rstudio.  Thanks in advance for any kind of help.

Comment: use `gather()` from `tidyr` package.

Comment: I wonder how your data is structured, as `365 * 18 = 6570` not 9587.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly sure if this is what you are asking for, but here is one approach to get pairs of lat/long given the data:

```
df <- read.table(text = '          70.875 71.125 71.375 71.625 71.875 72.125
33.1251      0      0      0      0      0      0
33.3751      0      0      0      0      0      0
33.6251      0      0      0      0      0      0
33.8751      0      0      0      0      0      0
34.1251      0      0      0      0      0      0
34.3751      0      0      0      0      0      0', header = TRUE)
expand.grid(row.names(df), gsub('X', '', names(df)))
```

Output in this case will be 36 rows as follows:

```
      Var1   Var2
1  33.1251 70.875
2  33.3751 70.875
3  33.6251 70.875
4  33.8751 70.875
5  34.1251 70.875
6  34.3751 70.875
7  33.1251 71.125
8  33.3751 71.125
9  33.6251 71.125
10 33.8751 71.125
11 34.1251 71.125
```

Note, I am using `gsub` above because the `read.table` pre-pended `X` to the colnames (non-numeric). Otherwise, you can skip that step.

EDIT: Adding this new stuff based on comment below....If you have a matrix such as this, you can convert to a data frame of row/col pairs and corresponding values as follows:

```
m <- matrix(1:40, nrow = 5)
row.names(m) <- 1:5
colnames(m) <- 1:8
df <- expand.grid(row = row.names(m), col = colnames(m))
df$value <- apply(df, 1, function(x) m[x[1], x[2]])
```

I made `row` and `col` as names above. Those could be your lat/long values easily.

EDIT: Adding an option to spread all data into single row by using lat/long (row/col in the simulated data above):

Using `tidyr` you can use the above data frame and spread into single row like this:

```
library(tidyr)
df %>% unite(rowcol, row, col) %>% spread(rowcol, value)
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response it works well to make pairs of latitude and longitude but how we can extract observations along with the lat lon pairs @ Gopala

Comment: That works perfectly and can you tell one mores step to gather all values(365) of specific lat/lon (address/grid) in one row.

Comment: df %>% unite(rowcol, row, col) %>% spread(rowcol, value), this command does not work to extract all values of certain lat/lon in one row.